# How to solve the JSON Exception?

Tags: android, json

I am getting bellow exception when using JSON.

```
06-21 18:59:43.418: W/System.err(682): org.json.JSONException: Value null at PunchTime of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject
06-21 18:59:43.428: W/System.err(682):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:96)
06-21 18:59:43.428: W/System.err(682):  at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:573)
06-21 18:59:43.428: W/System.err(682):  at com.android.epay.TestClass1.getEmployeeList(TestClass1.java:281)
06-21 18:59:43.428: W/System.err(682):  at com.android.epay.TestClass1$GroupPunch_task.doInBackground(TestClass1.java:214)
06-21 18:59:43.438: W/System.err(682):  at com.android.epay.TestClass1$GroupPunch_task.doInBackground(TestClass1.java:1)
06-21 18:59:43.438: W/System.err(682):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
06-21 18:59:43.438: W/System.err(682):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-21 18:59:43.438: W/System.err(682):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-21 18:59:43.438: W/System.err(682):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
06-21 18:59:43.448: W/System.err(682):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
06-21 18:59:43.448: W/System.err(682):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

My code is..

```
j_obj = new JSONObject(responseBody);
JSONArray sites = j_obj.getJSONArray("details");
String date_new = null;
for (int i = 0; i < sites.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject list_obj = sites.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject type = list_obj.getJSONObject("****");
    JSONObject time = type.getJSONObject("@@@@@");
    String name = list_obj.getString("#####");
    String id = list_obj.getString("id");
    String _no = list_obj.getString("num");
    String type = type.getString("type");


    if (punchtime == null || punchtime.equals("")) {
        date_new = "Null Values";

    } else {

        year = time.getString("Year");
        month = time.getString("Month");
        day = time.getString("Day");
        hours = time.getString("Hours");
        minutes = time.getString("Minutes");
        seconds = time.getString("Seconds");
        millisec = time.getString("Milliseconds");
        date_new = month + "-" + day + "-" + year + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":" + millisec;
        System.out.println("New Date " + date_new);
    }

    _arrayList.add(id);
    arryList.add(name);
    _arrayList.add(_no);
    punchType_arrayList.add(type);
    punchTime_arrayList.add(date_new);

}


System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

} finally {
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
}
```

Why ia m getting this error? I used if else, still am having same problem.
I searched so many sites but i didn't get answer for it.
please help ...

Comment: where is punchtime  initialized ?

Comment: have you checked your json on jsonlint.com

Comment: Probably not directly related, but you'll get a NullPointerException `if (punchtime == null ...` when you call `punchtime.getString(date_new);`

Answer (score 0):

a few things here:

```
 if (punchtime == null || punchtime.equals("")) {
    date_new = "Null Values";
    punchtime.getString(date_new);
 }
```

What do you think is going to happen here if the first condition of this if statement is fulfilled? It will be null. Calling a method on an object that is null will give you a NullPointerException.

Secondly can you post the JSON string that you're trying to parse? It's possible that there's an error in the JSON string.